# Gson assigns null values when there are values in the json input

Tags: json, gson

I get null for objects when there is a value in the json. It happens with the first object.
Here is the json:

```json
{
  "quakeml": {
    "eventParameters": {
        "event": [
              {
          "description": [
            {
              "text": "S0959a",
              "type": "earthquake name"
            }
          ],
          "origin": {
            "longitude": {
              "value": 135.6234
            },
            "latitude": {
              "value": 4.5024
            },
            "distance": {
              "value": 32.5
            }
          },
          "magnitude": [
            {
              "mag": {
                "value": 3.2
              },
              "type": "MbS",
              "originID": "smi:insight.mqs/origin/20220623-123048/ebd6d417"
            },
            {
              "mag": {
                "value": 3.2
              },
              "type": "MbP",
              "originID": "smi:insight.mqs/origin/20220623-123048/ebd6d417"
            },
            {
              "mag": {
                "value": 3,
                "lowerUncertainty": 0.4,
                "upperUncertainty": 0.4
              },
              "type": "MWspec",
              "originID": "smi:insight.mqs/origin/20220623-123048/ebd6d417"
            },
            {
              "mag": {
                "value": 3,
                "lowerUncertainty": 0.4,
                "upperUncertainty": 0.4
              },
              "type": "MW",
              "originID": "smi:insight.mqs/origin/20220623-123048/ebd6d417"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "description": [
            {
              "text": "S0959a",
              "type": "earthquake name"
            }
          ],
          "origin": {
            "longitude": {
              "value": 135.6234
            },
            "latitude": {
              "value": 4.5024
            },
            "distance": {
              "value": 32.5
            }
          },
          "magnitude": [
            {
              "mag": {
                "value": 3.2
              },
              "type": "MbS",
              "originID": "smi:insight.mqs/origin/20220623-123048/ebd6d417"
            },
            {
              "mag": {
                "value": 3.2
              },
              "type": "MbP",
              "originID": "smi:insight.mqs/origin/20220623-123048/ebd6d417"
            },
            {
              "mag": {
                "value": 3,
                "lowerUncertainty": 0.4,
                "upperUncertainty": 0.4
              },
              "type": "MWspec",
              "originID": "smi:insight.mqs/origin/20220623-123048/ebd6d417"
            },
            {
              "mag": {
                "value": 3,
                "lowerUncertainty": 0.4,
                "upperUncertainty": 0.4
              },
              "type": "MW",
              "originID": "smi:insight.mqs/origin/20220623-123048/ebd6d417"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }``
}
```

Here is the gson call:

```java
Example example=null;
example = gson.fromJson(content, Example.class);
```

I get the error that Example.getQuakeml() is a null. Here is Example class. The class is the standard class created when using a tool that creates java POJOs. That creates standard java beans for gson and also creates the proper annotations for gson.:

```java
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("quakeml")
    @Expose
    private Quakeml quakeml;

    public Quakeml getQuakeml() {
        return quakeml;
    }

    public void setQuakeml(Quakeml quakeml) {
        this.quakeml = quakeml;
    }

}
```

When I use debug I discover that the variable example is null for this standard gson call:

```java
Quakeml quakeml = example.getQuakeml();
```

I really appreciate the help!
Thanks!!

Comment: Can you please include how exactly you are calling `Gson` methods? Are you using any obfuscation or code shrinking tool such as ProGuard?

Comment: Example example=null;
example = gson.fromJson(content, Example.class);

Comment: I had them in the message below the json. I do not use proguard. I still suspect that is something about the json. It was created from xml I found for the data I wanted. It passes a json check I found on the web. Thanks Marcono1234 for helping. This is for a bunch of schools worldwide.

Comment: Your JSON contains \`\`; I assume that is a copy & paste error since you said it passed JSON validation. How are you creating the `Gson` instance, could you please include that code in the question as well? Could you please also include your complete code starting from the call to `fromJson` to the call `getQuakeml()`. Maybe you are ignoring an exception thrown by Gson?

Comment: Yep I just found it myself. But you should get the credit!

Comment: Just not sure how to do that officially and close it out. lol

Comment: If I understand you correctly this was indeed caused by the \`\` in the JSON, making it malformed. Therefore I have voted to close this question (I hope that is the right approach).

Comment: yep I believe you are right!